# Error trying Hadoop Mapreduce example in hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: mapreduce, resourcemanager

I have the following. 
Namenode and Datanode seem to work just fine.
But Resourcemanager and Nodemanager seem to have some kind weird config problem i can't find.
On first glance everything looks fine because every webgui is responding. 
But if I execute

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /input /out2
```

I get the following error

```
2014-02-04 08:57:05,906 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1345)) -  map 0% reduce 0%
2014-02-04 08:57:14,146 INFO  [main] ipc.Client (Client.java:handleConnectionFailure(783)) - Retrying connect to server: datanode0/10.80.10.132:59135. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2014-02-04 08:57:15,147 INFO  [main] ipc.Client (Client.java:handleConnectionFailure(783)) -     Retrying connect to server: datanode0/10.80.10.132:59135. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2014-02-04 08:57:16,149 INFO  [main] ipc.Client (Client.java:handleConnectionFailure(783)) - Retrying connect to server: datanode0/10.80.10.132:59135. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
```

Which ist really strange because the config says something diffrent

```
<name>yarn.nodemanager.address</name>
<value>${yarn.nodemanager.hostname}:36123</value>
```

Which is really weird because I can't figure out why he takes port 59135... which btw is always some random port. 
Can anybody point me in the right direction to find the error

Answer (score 0):

For Hadoop 2.2.x installation guide follow this link

http://nextgenhadoop.blogspot.in/2013/10/steps-to-install-hadoop-220-stable.html

Answer (score 0):

When I was running Hadoop locally, I had the same symptoms. I discovered that I needed to add the following to yarn-site.xml to get things working properly:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
  <value>127.0.0.1:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
  <value>127.0.0.1:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
  <value>127.0.0.1:8031</value>
</property>
```

In your case, you would need to set the proper value for each of these properties, depending on where you are trying to access. Do you have these properties configured?

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't run it or want to run it on one machine. I have a view VMs for it. These values seem fine ... or they have all the default values. But do you mean a Nodemanager should have not 0.0.0.0 as a hostname, but 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you must run it on 1 machine; only that you need to configure these properties. 127.0.0.1 is localhost - the machine you're running on - I just used it as an example. You should use the correct host IP address or DNS name for your server.

Comment: these properties are set... I still wonder why it uses a random port to connect to the nodemanager

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure host name and port number in all nodes not just only in resource manager node